# Unknown Type Name 'studentController'

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am making a table view application and it will not recognize the type studentController in the studentAddController.h. I have a previous project that I looked at and cannot figure out why it can not recognize the type name.

Here is the code in the studentController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "studentCells.h"
 #import "AssignmentsController.h"
 #import "studentAddController.h"


 @interface studentController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *studentArray;
 }
 - (IBAction)addStudentButton:(id)sender;
 - (void)insertNewRow:(NSDictionary *)studentDictionary;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *studentTableView;

 @end
```

Here is the code in the studentController.m

```
#import "studentController.h"

@implementation studentController

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
self =[super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 studentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
}

- (IBAction)addStudentButton:(id)sender {
     studentAddController *studentAddView =[self.storyboard       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"studentAddView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:studentAddView animated:YES];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [studentArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *studentCellIdentifier = @"studentCell";
studentCells *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:studentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSDictionary *studentDictionary = [studentArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[cell.firstNameCellLabel setText:[studentDictionary objectForKey:@"First Name"]];
[cell.lastNameCellLabel setText:[studentDictionary objectForKey:@"Last Name"]];
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
AssignmentsController *assignmentView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"assignmentView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:assignmentView animated:YES];
}

-(void)insertNewRow:(NSDictionary *)studentDictionary {
[studentArray addObject:studentDictionary];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[studentArray count] -1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

}

@end
```

Here is the code for studentAddController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "studentController.h"
#import "studentAddController.h"

@interface studentAddController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastNameField;

- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)keyboardResign:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) studentController *parentTableVC;

@end
```

Here is the code in the studentAddController.m

```
#import "studentAddController.h"

@implementation studentAddController

- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {
NSDictionary *studentDictionary =@{ @"First Name" : [self.firstNameField text],
                                    @"Last Name" : [self.lastNameField text]
                                    };
[self.parentTableVC insertNewRow:studentDictionary];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)keyboardResign:(id)sender {

[self resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference. In `studentController.h` you import `studentAddController.h` and in `studentAddController.h` you import `studentController.h`. Try making these changes to your headers:

studentController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "studentCells.h"
#import "AssignmentsController.h"
```

studentController.m

```
#import "studentController.h"
#import "studentAddController.h"
```

studentAddController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "studentController.h"
```

I would also note that naming standards would dictate your classes are PascalCase not camelCase. Only your variables and methods should be camelCase.

I would also note that you didn't need to import studentAddController in studentController.h so I just moved it to the .m.  If you actually needed to import studentAddController then you would do a forward class declaration to avoid a circular reference. Like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "studentCells.h"
#import "AssignmentsController.h"

@class studentAddController;
```